# Retreiving <TD> tag from table on website using VBA and put into excel

Tags: html, vba, excel, conditional-statements

I am trying to retrieve information from a `<TD>` tag on a website.

It works but I cant seem to get the text from the second `<td>` tag in a `<TR>` tag while using a conditional statement to get the second  tag as this is he only way I see that works. The code works fine to extract information I just cant figure out how to access that second  with the condition that I have found a match in the first `<td>`.

So the actual html table would look like this.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table id="Table2">
<tr>
  <td class="tSystemRight">System Name: -if this matches</td>
  <td class="tSystemLeft breakword">Windows3756 -I need this</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="tSystemRight">System Acronym: -if this matches</td>
  <td class="tSystemLeft breakword">WIN37  -I need this</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The VBA script I have is:

```
excelRow = 2

For Each tr In msxml.tableRows
cellCount = 1
   For Each TD In tr.getElementsByTagName("TD")
    If ((cellCount = 1) And (TD.innerText = "System Acronym:")) Then
       Worksheets("Data").Cells(excelRow, 2).value = Cells(1, 2)
    ElseIf ((cellCount = 1) And (TD.innerText = "System Name:")) Then
       Worksheets("Data").Cells(excelRow, 3).value = Cells(1, 2)
    cellCount = cellCount + 1
    End If
   Next
Next
```

This just displays `System Name:` and `System Acronym:` in the excel sheet

Comment: `Cells(1, 2)` is not assigned any parentage. Try something like `TD.Cells(1,2)` or `tr.cells(1,2)` *(I may not have exact syntax, as it's been a while since I worked with html tables in vba, but I think you get the idea).*

Comment: Maybe try something like `Cells(2,2)`. Since you're already getting the text from the cell above, adjust your counter to get the next one down?

Comment: those didn't work for me. I will keep trying

Comment: Your script is missing a `Next` for `For Each TD`, or `For each tr ...` - is that all the code you have?

Comment: can you share URL? also ... try `td.Cells(0,1)` or `tr.cells(0,1)`. If I remember correctly table counting in HTML is 0 based. So what appears as Row 1 is Row 0 in code (same with columns).

Comment: The website cant be accessed by the general public. I have more code and the Next are there I just didn't add them on this site. I thought maybe there was another way to access that second tag with the conditional statement. Its literally a table with a bunch of rows. Keep in mind I can access data fine and it works when I only want the first `<TD>`. Ok I will try that.

Comment: It is hard to identify problem with very small piece of code - where do you get Cells(1, 2) populated? Also try to do some debugging and share results, do you get inside 'If' or 'ElseIf' statement? what are values of Cells(1,2)? You have far more info and control then we do,  use it! :)

Comment: ive done loads of debugging. I am using Cells(1,2) to get the innertext out of the second `TD>` tag. Of course it displays nothing. Td.innertext always shows what's inside of the`<TD>` tag. When I use TD.Cells(,) I get an error like object doesn't support this property or method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `td` element and you want to get the inner text of the next `td` in the row then use the `nextSibling` property, like this:

```
For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("TD")
    If ((cellCount = 1) And (td.innerText = "System Acronym:")) Then
       Worksheets("Data").Cells(excelRow, 2).Value = td.NextSibling.innerText
    ElseIf ((cellCount = 1) And (td.innerText = "System Name:")) Then
       Worksheets("Data").Cells(excelRow, 3).Value = td.NextSibling.innerText
    cellCount = cellCount + 1
    End If
   Next
Next
```

Note that nothing in the given code is changing the value of `excelRow` so everything will keep getting written into the same row. Also note that the HTML given has the "System Name" first and the "System Acronym" second whereas the code seems to be structured to look for "System Acronym" first and "System Name" second

Answer (score 2):

I developed the following from a public website with almost identical structure to yours. (https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h3/current/)

Requires Reference to `Microsoft Internet Controls` and `Microsoft HTML Object Library`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As New HTMLDocument

With ie

    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h3/current/"

    'can place code to wait for IE to load here .. I skipped it since its not in direct focus of question

    Set doc = .Document

    Dim t As HTMLTable
    Dim r As HTMLTableRow
    Dim c As HTMLTableCol

    Set t = doc.getElementById("t1tg1")

    'loop through each row
    For Each r In t.Rows

        If r.Cells(0).innerText = "Mar. 2016" Then Debug.Print r.Cells(1).innerText

        'loop through each column in the row
        'For Each c In r.Cells

        '    Debug.Print c.innerText

        'Next

    Next

End With

End Sub
```

All that said, after setting your specific table like I have above, I suggest the following edit to your code (I have left out the cellcount check and other stuff):

```
For Each r In t.Rows

    'find out which columns System Acronym and value will be and modify the Cells(n) statements          
    If r.Cells(0).innerText = "System Acronym:" Then Worksheets("Data").Cells(excelRow, 2).Value = r.Cells(2).innerText

Next
```